# Show $\frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2}{a^2} +3 \ge 2\left(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}\right)$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I want to verify the following inequality:

Let $a, b$ be non negative number

$$\frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2}{a^2} +3 \ge 2\left(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}\right)$$

I decided to analyse the sign of $$\frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2}{a^2} +3  - 2\left(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}\right)$$

But I'm not getting anywhere.

I'm having trouble deciding whether $\dfrac{a^2(a-2)+b^2(b-2)}{ab} +3$ is positive or negative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $t=a/b+b/a$. Then this becomes $t^2+1\geq 2t$, which is same as $(t-1)^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: sharp substitution...

Comment: @imranfat Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You actually can prove for +2 also like $\frac{a^2}{b^2}+1\geq 2\frac{a}{b}$ and
$\frac{b^2}{a^2}+1\geq 2\frac{b}{a}$ by AM-GM and by adding you get the desire result.